# make user_id equal to username

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following code in php

```
// Get all the questions 
$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM da_questions INNER JOIN da_users ORDER BY da_questions.question_id DESC");

$allquestions = array(); 

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
{
    $allquestions[] = $row;
}
```

How can I make the `user_id` in `table da_questions` be equal to the `user_id` in `da_users` so when I do the following I get the correct username for the correct user id.

```
<?php foreach($allquestions as $question): ?>

    <span><b><?php echo $question['question_title']; ?><span class="pull-right"><?php echo $question['username']; ?></span></b></span>
    <hr style="margin-top:0px;" />
    <p><?php echo $question['question_text']; ?></p>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: All I can think of when I read your queries is "Daaaa bears."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `ON` condition in your join

```
SELECT * 
FROM da_questions 
INNER JOIN da_users ON da_users.user_id = da_questions.user_id
ORDER BY da_questions.question_id DESC
```

Comment: How did you get that from the question asked? Truly impressive psychic abilities!